# Tomato sauce with flavourant vowels

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Cathedral returns warm air, a madness (10)
> 2. All-salad cave mixes up historical house (12)
> 3. Endless tomato sauce with flavourant vowels gives Casbah mosque (9)
> 4. Dirk C.O. Rosalyn backed off a monolith (7)
> 5. Sequel masker scrambles city plaza (12)
> 6. Spanish Diego's apple is exhibition complex (17)
> 7. Guitarist Steve and South American capital make writer's residence (7)
> 8. Formula 1 location confused D analysis (9)
> 9. Fortification scales out incoherently (9)
> 10. Large bird with recognised safety professional inside small bird become wildlife reserve (10)
> 11. Mameluk at an upside-down observation tower (7)
> 12. Tall structure shuffles tiebreaker two (13)
> 13. Archaeological site backs peanut I ejected (6)
> 14. Laminated mac rearranges Levantine ruins (12)
> 15. Boleyn Zappa residence is biographical museum (14)
> 16. Ancient citadel is confounded ??? pro (???)

Solve all clues and find the missing word to complete clue #16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
1   Cathedral returns warm air, a madness (10)
```

> warM AIR A MADNEss backwards is the ENDA MARIAM cathedral in Asmara, Eritrea.

```
2   All-salad cave mixes up historical house (12)
```

> CASA DE LA VALL is a historical house in Andorra la Vella, Andorra (all salad cave rearranged).

```
3   Endless tomato sauce with flavourant vowels gives Casbah mosque (9)
```

> As found by @JR_M, KETCHAOUA is a mosque in Algiers, Algeria. (Ketchup - up plus vowels in flavourant). Thanks, @JR_M!

```
4   Dirk C.O. Rosalyn backed off a monolith (7)
```

> dirK CO ROSAlyn reverses is ASO ROCK, an outcropping just outside Abuja, Nigeria.

```
5   Sequel masker scrambles city plaza (12)
```

> MESKEL SQUARE, the city centre of Addis Ababa, Ethiopia (sequel masker rearranged).

```
6   Spanish Diego's apple is exhibition complex (17)
```

> MANZANA DE LA RIVERA is an exhibition complex in Asuncion, Paraguay. (Apple in Spanish is MANZANA, and it belongs to Diego RIVERA, a famous Mexican painter. So it is Rivera’s Apple => Apple of Rivera in Spanish).

```
7   Guitarist Steve and South American capital make writer's residence (7)
```

> VAILIMA, the last home of Robert Louis Stevenson, is just south of Apia, Samoa. (Guitarist Steve VAI + LIMA, Peru).

```
8   Formula 1 location confused D analysis (9)
```

> YAS ISLAND, in Abu Dhabi, UAE is the site of the F1 Etihad Airways Abu Dhabi Grand Prix (D analysis rearranged).

```
9   Fortification scales out incoherently (9)
```

> @Dr Xorile found that OSU CASTLE, near Accra, Ghana is a fortification (scales out, rearranged). Thanks, @Dr Xorile!

```
10  Large bird with recognised safety professional inside small bird become wildlife reserve (10)
```

> LEMURS PARK is a wildlife reserve in Antananarivo, Madagascar. (Large bird EMU, recognized safety professional RSP, small bird LARK => L + EMU + RSP + ARK).

```
11  Mameluk at an upside-down observation tower (7)
```

> mamELUK AT An backwards yields ATAKULE, a communications tower in Ankara, Turkey.

```
12  Tall structure shuffles tiebreaker two (13)
```

> BAITEREK TOWER is a tall structure in Astana, Kazakhstan (tiebreaker two rearranged).

```
13  Archaeological site backs peanut I ejected (6)
```

> PeaNUT I EJected backwards yields JEITUN, an archaeological site north of Ashgabat, Turkmenistan.

```
14  Laminated mac rearranges Levantine ruins (12)
```

> AMMAN CITADEL, in Amman, Jordan (Laminated Mac rearranged).

```
15  Boleyn Zappa residence is biographical museum (14)
```

> This is the ANNE FRANK HOUSE in Amsterdam, The Netherlands. (Anne Boleyn + Frank Zappa + (house = residence) )

```
16  Ancient citadel is confounded ??? pro (???)
```

> I think the clue should be *Ancient citadel is confounded* **social** *pro* **(9)**. This leads to ACROPOLIS, the famous ancient citadel in Athens, Greece. (Social pro rearranged).

Looks like the common theme is

> Tourist attractions in capital cities starting with A!

Comment: Great work. The remaining capitals are Accra (Ghana), Antananarivo (Madagascar), and Athens (Greece). Obviously, counting Algiers from @JR_M's answer

Comment: So maybe Osu Castle near Accra for #7

Comment: Thanks, @DrXorile! I think you’re right for 9!

Comment: Poor Accra.......fun puzzle!

Comment: And another tick for @El-Guest! Nice work once again :)

Comment: Thank you @jafe! Loving these geography puzzles, one of my favourite topics!! :D

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

3 Endless tomato sauce with flavourant vowels gives Casbah mosque (9)

> tomato sauce = **Ketchup** but endless ketchup is **Ketch**. The vowels in flavourant are **aoua**. Together they make **Ketchaoua** which is a mosque in Algiers, Algeria.

7 Guitarist Steve and South American capital make writer's residence (7)

> Steve **Vai** and Capital of Peru **Lima**, make **Vailima** which was the residence of Robert Louis Stevenson.

16 Ancient citadel is confounded ??? pro (???)

> Would the missing word be **Social**? Social pro mixed up would be **Acropolis** and the missing number would be **9**. The Acropolis is an ancient citadel in Athens, Greece.

Comment: Great answers! :D +1 from me!